# Photon Unity GetRoomList() is always empty

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Currently I'm trying to make a matchmakingsystem for my game with the photon networkingsystem. I already can create rooms and join into them, however if I try to use the PhotonNetwork.getRoomList() function the array is always empty. Following the network status string I know that I am in the standard lobby.

My Code:

```
void fillBrowser()
{
    Debug.Log("Checking for Rooms");
    if(PhotonNetwork.insideLobby)
    {
        Debug.Log("Inside a Lobby");
        Debug.Log(PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList().ToString());
    }
}
```

Returns:

Checking for Rooms

Inside a Lobby

RoomInfo[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output `RoomInfo[]` says that it returned an array of `RoomInfo`s. You get this output because you called `ToString()` on an array. Save the  returned `RoomInfo[]` to a variable, loop through them, and see what info they contain.

```
void fillBrowser()
{
    Debug.Log("Checking for Rooms");
    if(PhotonNetwork.insideLobby)
    {
        Debug.Log("Inside a Lobby");
        var rooms = PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList();
        foreach(var room in rooms) 
             Debug.Log("Found room: " + room.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried out your code and still only got the Checking for Rooms and Inside a Lobby returns. Does anybody know if the method if the Function GetRoomList is deprecated?

Comment: Then the enumeration which `GetRoomLists()` returns must be empty. Log `rooms.Length` to the console to make sure. Maybe this is also a problem related to http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/pun-photonnetwork-getroomlist-problem.311300/

Comment: When I try to monitor it it always stays zero. I am starting the room in a second client and check the list in a second client. Maybe my CreateRoom  Code might be the error: 
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions() { isVisible = false, maxPlayers = 4 };

        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom("Test",roomOptions,TypedLobby.Default);

Comment: So have you tried setting the room's visibility to 'true' already? (isVisble = true)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

Debug.Log(string.Concat(GetRoomList().Select(x => x.name + "\n\r").ToArray()));
```

or

```
using System.Linq;

GetRoomList().ToList().ForEach(x => { Debug.Log(x.name); });
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry m answering bit late..
just add 
**"PhotonNetwork.autoJoinLobby = true;" in the void Awake()** 
function and everything will work smoothly ;)